# Check shell programs for portability

Tags: c, strings, shell

There are lots of shell programs that have `/bin/sh` as interpreter, yet use some features that are specific to bash or other popular shells. I have written a little program that detects these unportable features. It is not meant to compete with ShellCheck, its purpose is only to catch a few common mistakes.

Since the program checks for portability issues, I had to lead by example and make this program as portable as possible as well. Therefore I sticked to the headers and functions provided by C99.

Since C is a dangerous programming language with lots of ways to shoot yourself in the foot, the first half of the code defines an API for the second half of the code, which starts at `typedef enum`. This API is easier to use than the standard C functions for dealing with strings. It takes some ideas from C++ (`nullptr`, `npos`) and Go (immutable strings defined by `(data, len)`, herein called `cstr`), and probably from several other languages as well.

Implementing generic functions with callbacks is quite verbose in C. I really like that the code in `foreach_3_fields_in_line` is trivial to understand. This simplicity comes at the cost of having to define a `struct` for the callback parameters. If standard C had nested function scopes, I would have used an inner function, and the code would have been much shorter. Maybe there is a more elegant way of implementing `checkline_sh_test_eqeq`, for now that's all I have, and it works well.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define nullptr ((void *) 0)
static const size_t npos = -1;

static bool
is_alnum(char c)
{
    return isalnum((unsigned char) c) != 0;
}

static bool
is_hspace(char c)
{
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
}

// cstr is a constant string view.
typedef struct {
    const char *data; // never nullptr
    size_t len;
} cstr;

#define CSTR(str) ((cstr) { str, strlen(str) })

static const char *
cstr_charptr(cstr s)
{
    assert(memchr(s.data, 0, s.len) == nullptr);
    assert(s.data[s.len] == '\0');
    return s.data;
}

#if 0 /* unused */
static bool
cstr_ends_with(cstr s, cstr suffix)
{
    if (suffix.len > s.len)
        return false;
    const char *start = s.data + s.len - suffix.len;
    return memcmp(start, suffix.data, suffix.len) == 0;
}
#endif

static bool
cstr_starts_with(cstr s, cstr prefix)
{
    if (prefix.len > s.len)
        return false;
    return memcmp(s.data, prefix.data, prefix.len) == 0;
}

static cstr
cstr_substr(cstr s, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    assert(start <= s.len);
    assert(end <= s.len);
    assert(end - start <= s.len);
    return (cstr) { s.data + start, end - start };
}

static size_t
cstr_index(cstr haystack, cstr needle)
{
    if (needle.len > haystack.len)
        return npos;
    size_t limit = haystack.len - needle.len;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= limit; i++)
        if (memcmp(haystack.data + i, needle.data, needle.len) == 0)
            return i;
    return npos;
}

static bool
cstr_contains_char(cstr haystack, char needle)
{
    return memchr(haystack.data, needle, haystack.len);
}

static bool
cstr_contains(cstr haystack, cstr needle)
{
    return cstr_index(haystack, needle) != npos;
}

static size_t
cstr_rindex(cstr haystack, cstr needle)
{
    if (needle.len > haystack.len)
        return npos;
    size_t limit = haystack.len - needle.len;
    for (size_t i = limit + 1; i-- > 0; )
        if (memcmp(haystack.data + i, needle.data, needle.len) == 0)
            return i;
    return npos;
}

static bool
cstr_eq(cstr s1, cstr s2)
{
    return s1.len == s2.len
        && memcmp(s1.data, s2.data, s1.len) == 0;
}

static cstr
cstr_next_field(cstr line, size_t *pidx)
{
    size_t idx = *pidx;
    while (idx < line.len && is_hspace(line.data[idx]))
        idx++;
    size_t start = idx;
    while (idx < line.len && !is_hspace(line.data[idx]))
        idx++;
    *pidx = idx;
    return cstr_substr(line, start, idx);
}

static cstr
cstr_right_of_last(cstr s, cstr delimiter)
{
    size_t i = cstr_rindex(s, delimiter);
    if (i == npos)
        return s;
    return cstr_substr(s, i + delimiter.len, s.len);
}

// str is a modifiable string buffer.
typedef struct {
    char *data;
    size_t len;
    size_t cap;
} str;

#define STR_EMPTY { nullptr, 0, 0 }

static cstr
str_c(str *s)
{
    assert(s->data != nullptr);
    return (cstr) { s->data, s->len };
}

static void
str_free(str *s)
{
    free(s->data);
}

static void
str_reserve(str *s, size_t n)
{
    size_t req_len = s->len + n;
    assert(req_len >= s->len);
    if (req_len <= s->cap)
        return;

    size_t new_cap = s->cap == 0 ? 64 : 2 * s->cap;
    if (new_cap == 0)
        new_cap = -1;

    char *new_data = realloc(s->data, new_cap);
    if (new_data == nullptr) {
        perror(nullptr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    s->data = new_data;
    s->cap = new_cap;
}

static void
str_append_char(str *s, char c)
{
    str_reserve(s, 1);
    s->data[s->len++] = c;
}

static const char *
str_charptr(str *s)
{
    str_reserve(s, 1);
    s->data[s->len] = '\0';
    assert(memchr(s->data, '\0', s->len) == nullptr);
    return s->data;
}

static bool
str_read_line(str *s, FILE *f)
{
    int c;

    s->len = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF && c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
        str_append_char(s, (char) c);
    }
    return c != EOF;
}

static bool
str_read_text_line(str *s, FILE *f)
{
    int c;

    s->len = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(f)) > '\0' && c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
        str_append_char(s, (char) c);
    }
    assert(c != '\0');
    return c != EOF;
}

typedef enum {
    W_how_to_fix,
    W_dollar_random,
    W_test_eqeq,
    W_double_bracket
} warning_kind;

static unsigned long explained = 0;

static void
explain(warning_kind warning, ...)
{
    unsigned long mask = 1UL << warning;
    if ((explained & mask) != 0)
        return;
    explained |= mask;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, warning);
    printf("\n");
    const char *line;
    while ((line = va_arg(args, const char *)) != nullptr)
        printf("%s%s\n", line[0] == '\0' ? "" : "\t", line);
    printf("\n");
    va_end(args);
}

static void
explain_how_to_fix(void)
{
    explain(
        W_how_to_fix,
        "To fix this message, decide whether this file is necessary",
        "for the package to build. Then choose any of these variants:",
        "",
        "1.  Add a patch for the file",
        "    (see https://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/pkgsrc.html#components.patches)",
        "2.  Add a SUBST block for the file to the package Makefile",
        "    (see mk/subst.mk)",
        "3.  Add CHECK_PORTABILITY_SKIP+= shell/glob to the package Makefile",
        "    (see mk/check/check-portability.mk)",
        nullptr);
}

static size_t
index_opening_bracket(cstr s)
{
    size_t index = cstr_index(s, CSTR("[["));
    if (index == npos)
        return npos;
    if (index > 0 && !is_hspace(s.data[index - 1]))
        return npos;
    if (index + 2 < s.len && !is_hspace(s.data[index + 2]))
        return npos;
    return index;
}

static size_t
index_closing_bracket(cstr s)
{
    size_t index = cstr_index(s, CSTR("]]"));
    if (index == npos)
        return npos;
    if (index > 0 && !is_hspace(s.data[index - 1]))
        return npos;
    if (index + 2 < s.len && !is_hspace(s.data[index + 2]) && s.data[index + 2] != ';')
        return npos;
    return index;
}

static size_t nerrors = 0;

static bool
is_shell_comment(cstr line)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    cstr f1 = cstr_next_field(line, &i);
    return cstr_starts_with(f1, CSTR("#"));
}

static void
checkline_sh_double_brackets(cstr filename, size_t lineno, cstr line)
{
    if (is_shell_comment(line))
        return;

    size_t opening_index = index_opening_bracket(line);
    if (opening_index == npos)
        return;

    cstr suffix = cstr_substr(line, opening_index, line.len);
    size_t closing_index = index_closing_bracket(suffix);
    if (closing_index == npos)
        return;

    printf("%s:%zu:%zu: double brackets: %s\n",
        cstr_charptr(filename), lineno, opening_index + 1,
        cstr_charptr(line));
    nerrors++;
    explain(
        W_double_bracket,
        "The keyword [[ is only available in bash, not in other shells.",
        "Since it is typically used inside an if statement, if that",
        "command is missing, it is interpreted as a \"no\".",
        "",
        "An error message of the form \"[[: command not found\"",
        "is logged, but that is easy to overlook in the large",
        "output of the build process.",
        nullptr);
    explain_how_to_fix();
}

// Check for $RANDOM, which is specific to ksh and bash.
static void
checkline_sh_dollar_random(cstr filename, size_t lineno, cstr line)
{
    // Note: This code does not find _all_ instances of
    // unportable code. If a single line contains an unsafe and
    // a safe usage of $RANDOM, it will pass the test.
    if (is_shell_comment(line))
        return;
    if (!cstr_contains(line, CSTR("$RANDOM")))
        return;

    // $RANDOM together with the PID is often found in GNU-style
    // configure scripts and is considered acceptable.
    if (cstr_contains(line, CSTR("$$-$RANDOM")))
  return;
 if (cstr_contains(line, CSTR("$RANDOM-$$")))
        return;

    // Variable names that only start with RANDOM are not special.
    size_t idx = cstr_index(line, CSTR("$RANDOM"));
    if (idx != npos && idx + 7 < line.len && is_alnum(line.data[idx + 7]))
        return;

    printf("%s:%zu:%zu: $RANDOM: %s\n",
        cstr_charptr(filename), lineno, idx + 1,
        cstr_charptr(line));
    explain(
        W_dollar_random,
        "The variable $RANDOM is not required for a POSIX-conforming shell, and",
        "many implementations of /bin/sh do not support it. It should therefore",
        "not be used in shell programs that are meant to be portable across a",
        "large number of POSIX-like systems.",
        nullptr);
    explain_how_to_fix();
}

typedef void (*foreach_3_fields_cb)(cstr f1, cstr f2, cstr f3, void *actiondata);

static void
foreach_3_fields_in_line(cstr line, foreach_3_fields_cb action, void *actiondata)
{
    size_t idx = 0;
    cstr f1 = cstr_next_field(line, &idx);
    cstr f2 = cstr_next_field(line, &idx);
    cstr f3 = cstr_next_field(line, &idx);

    while (f3.len > 0) {
        action(f1, f2, f3, actiondata);
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
        f3 = cstr_next_field(line, &idx);
    }
}

struct checkline_sh_test_eqeq_actiondata {
    cstr filename;
    size_t lineno;
    cstr line;
};

static void
checkline_sh_test_eqeq_action(cstr f1, cstr f2, cstr f3, void *actiondata)
{
    if (!cstr_eq(f3, CSTR("==")))
        return;
    if (!cstr_eq(f1, CSTR("test")) && !cstr_eq(f1, CSTR("[")))
        return;

    struct checkline_sh_test_eqeq_actiondata *ad = actiondata;
    printf(
        "%s:%zu:%zu: found test ... == ...: %s\n",
        cstr_charptr(ad->filename), ad->lineno,
        (size_t) (f3.data - ad->line.data),
        cstr_charptr(ad->line));
    explain(
        W_test_eqeq,
        "The \"test\" command, as well as the \"[\" command, are not required to know",
        "the \"==\" operator. Only a few implementations like bash and some",
        "versions of ksh support it.",
        "",
        "When you run \"test foo == foo\" on a platform that does not support the",
        "\"==\" operator, the result will be \"false\" instead of \"true\". This can",
        "lead to unexpected behavior.",
        nullptr);
    explain_how_to_fix();
}

static void
checkline_sh_test_eqeq(cstr filename, size_t lineno, cstr line)
{
    if (is_shell_comment(line))
        return;

    struct checkline_sh_test_eqeq_actiondata ad = { filename, lineno, line };
    foreach_3_fields_in_line(line, checkline_sh_test_eqeq_action, &ad);
}

static bool
is_shell_shebang(cstr line)
{
    if (!cstr_starts_with(line, CSTR("#!")))
        return false;

    size_t i = 2;
    cstr full_interp = cstr_next_field(line, &i);
    cstr arg = cstr_next_field(line, &i);

    cstr interp = cstr_right_of_last(full_interp, CSTR("/"));
    if (cstr_eq(interp, CSTR("env")) && arg.len > 0) {
        interp = arg;
    }

    return cstr_eq(interp, CSTR("sh"))
        || cstr_eq(interp, CSTR("ksh"))
        || cstr_eq(interp, CSTR("@SH@"))
        || cstr_eq(interp, CSTR("@SHELL@"));
}

static bool
is_irrelevant_extension(cstr ext)
{
    return cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("bz2"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("c"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("cc"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("cpp"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("gz"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("m4"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("pdf"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("ps"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("xz"))
        || cstr_eq(ext, CSTR("zip"));
}

static bool
skip_shebang(cstr basename)
{
    return cstr_eq(basename, CSTR("Makefile.am"))
        || cstr_eq(basename, CSTR("Makefile.in"))
        || cstr_eq(basename, CSTR("Makefile"));
}

static void
check_file(cstr filename)
{
    cstr basename = cstr_right_of_last(filename, CSTR("/"));
    cstr ext = cstr_right_of_last(basename, CSTR("."));
    if (is_irrelevant_extension(ext))
        return;

    FILE *f = fopen(cstr_charptr(filename), "rb");
    if (f == nullptr) {
        perror(cstr_charptr(filename));
        nerrors++;
        return;
    }

    str line = STR_EMPTY;

    size_t lineno = 0;
    if (!skip_shebang(basename)) {
        if (!str_read_line(&line, f))
            goto cleanup;
        lineno++;
        if (!is_shell_shebang(str_c(&line)))
            goto cleanup;
    }

    while (str_read_line(&line, f)) {
        cstr cline = str_c(&line);
        if (cstr_contains_char(str_c(&line), '\0'))
            break;
        lineno++;
        str_charptr(&line);

        checkline_sh_double_brackets(filename, lineno, cline);
        checkline_sh_dollar_random(filename, lineno, cline);
        checkline_sh_test_eqeq(filename, lineno, cline);
    }

cleanup:
    str_free(&line);

    (void) fclose(f);
}

static void
check_files_from_stdin(void)
{
    str line = STR_EMPTY;

    while (str_read_text_line(&line, stdin)) {
        str_charptr(&line);
        check_file(str_c(&line));
    }
}

static int
usage(const char *progname)
{
    fprintf(stderr,
        "usage: %s < file-list\n"
        "       %s file...\n",
        progname, progname);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1 && argv[1][0] == '-')
        return usage(argv[0]);
    if (argc == 1)
        check_files_from_stdin();
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        check_file(CSTR(argv[i]));
    return nerrors > 0 ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To test the code by manual inspection, [there are some example files](https://github.com/NetBSD/pkgsrc/tree/trunk/pkgtools/check-portability/files/testdata). Up to now, I haven't added an automatic test, even though it would be easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

### Spaces

My first read of this code:

```
    "The \"test\" command, as well as the \"[\" command, are not required to know",
    "the \"==\" operator. Only a few implementations like bash and some",
    "versions of ksh support it.",
```

was wrong; I didn't notice that it's actually a varargs-function accepting one line per argument. That's a little odd. This has the disadvantage of hard wraps regardless of actual console size, a significant departure from what people typically expect from a CLI.

The C-idiomatic way is to simply have one long string, potentially split onto multiple lines using implicit literal concatenation. The non-standardness of this pattern ties into my next point:

### C

Prepare for me to editorialize:

> C is a dangerous programming language with lots of ways to shoot yourself in the foot

You're right, and I don't particularly think that any of the structures you've put on top of it help to change that. In fact, you repeat some of the worst offenders, such as assignment-in-condition. In general I'd say that it isn't worth attempting to make C something that it isn't, and a much-smaller, idiomatic C program is easier to understand and maintain (particularly for others, if you open-source this) than a larger, non-idiomatic one.